# Powershell code for admin users in AD GROUPS

Tags: powershell, active-directory, localhost, admin, powershell-2.0

new to this sorry.
I have a list in notepad of LA GROUPS (example: LA-AAAAAA, LA-BBBBB, L-CCCCCC), and I need to find out a way to get the all the active users in these groups.
LA-AAAAA is created where AAAAA is the server name. So I am looking for a way to get all the users who are have access to the servers basically.
Anyone who is in the LA group has access. I have tried the code below but its giving my no data. the file exported with all the LA group names but does not show anyone in the list.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
$logtext = $null

$datenow = get-date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"

New-PSDrive -Name "R" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "**Path**"

    $LogfileName = "LA-group-members_"+ $datenow +"_4.txt"
    $Logfile = "R:\Logs\$LogfileName"
    $ServerList = Import-Csv **PATH**

    get-date *>> $Logfile

    foreach ($Server in $ServerList){
        $LaGroup = "LA-" + $Server.ServerName
        $logtext += "`n"
        $logtext += "$LaGroup"
        $logtext += "`n"
        $logtext += "---------------------------------------`n"
    
        $Members = Get-LocalGroupMember  #$LaGroup

        foreach ($Member in $Members){

            $logtext +=  $Member.name
            $logtext += "`n"
        }

        $logtext +=  "=======================================`n"

    }

#Write variable data to logfile
$logtext *>> $Logfile

Remove-PSDrive -Name "R"`your text
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to overcomplicate the code. `Get-LocalGroup LA-* -PV source | Get-LocalGroupMember | Select-Object @{ N ='Source'; E={ $source.Name }}, *`. Also unclear why the active directory tagged is being used.

Comment: The LA groups are in Active directory. In simple terms I just need some kind of code to print out all the users each of the groups I have in AD. thank you for your response Santiago

Comment: Why are you using `Get-Local*` cmdlets if the groups are in AD then?

Comment: I honestly am not used good at PowerShell, I was sent this code to work out as part of a project. Should I use GET-ADGROUP instead

Comment: Well yes, if you have that module available, you should `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(samAccountName=LA-*)'` for starters